# Pretty specific, but is "with your plate in your lap" a common expression in English?

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests

In Dutch we use it to refer to (the airtime of) tv-shows that start around dinner. Is there an equivalent to it?

I suppose it's sort of an idiom, but probably too specific to be considered so.

Comment: Since "with your plate in your lap" doesn't appear to refer to the **timing** of the programme, but rather how you watch it (while eating dinner), a couple of sentences using the phrase would be beneficial. English does have some stock phrases like "TV dinner", but the most suitable depends on exactly how you use yours.

Comment: Do people still govern their watching according to the time a show airs?

Comment: Agreeing with Andrew here... I believe some context in modern usage would benefit us. "TV Dinner" is what here in USA we called such meals, typically pre-packaged, but it has nothing to do with TV anymore. :)

Comment: Short answer is no, there is not such idiom in English. The time interval when such shows  are aired is known as *prime time*, and the prefab meals stereotypically associated with eating on the couch are known (or were, they've fallen out of favor) as *TV dinners*. It you elaborate a bit more on what the phrase means in Dutch and how it's used, particularly any connotations or subtexts, we could suggest more precise English analogs.

Comment: In British English I would say "Shall we eat off our laps tonight", or "Shall we have dinner on our laps tonight", or "Shall we just eat in front of the telly tonight". I have no idea how localised that is, but I believe everyone I know would understand exactly what I mean. However that doesn't extend in any way to an idiomatic description of TV programmes that start around mealtimes.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to refer to programmes in this time-slot, I would say "dinnertime TV", but this doesn't really indicate whether the viewers will actually be eating their dinner while watching the programme.

As the commenters above have said, there isn't an exactly equivalent expression in English.